# ClickDimensions: Survey answers into email template

Tags: freemarker, clickdimension

I am working with ClickDimensions surveys and the associated email template for auto responder. Currently I am trying to achieve one of the following:

1. Output a specific answer into the email (would be the best)
2. Output all answers like in the email notification

I have not found a way to navigate to the answers with FreeMarker yet.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not supported as per response from their support.